# "Unknown dump tag"

Tags: templating, debugging

I'm using Craft 2.6.2776. According to the [templating docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions), Craft extends the built-in [Twig templating functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/index.html), which it links to. Among those functions is [`dump()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html).

Here's the relevant part of my template:

```
{% dump(craft.request.getURL) %}
```

When I refresh the page, I get the error `Unknown "dump" tag.`.

It seems like `dump` should be supported, according to the docs. What's going on?

### Edit

I'm using VirtualHostX to run my PHP server, and the URL is xxx.dev. According to my `general.php` file, I am in dev mode:

```
  '.dev' => array(
    'enableTemplateCaching' => false,
    'siteUrl' => 'http://xxx.dev',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'baseUrl' => 'http://xxx.dev'
    ),
    'devMode' => true
  ),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dump tag is not a logic operator (e.g., no percent sign) — it should use the simple field brackets. As well, the proper format is either .url or .getUrl()

```
{{ dump(craft.request.url) }}
```

Comment: Of course I overlook the obvious.

Comment: ;) I've done the same way too many times.

Answer (score 5):

Twig's `dump` tag is only available when Craft's [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) is enabled.

Comment: `devMode` needs to be in the `'.dev'` array block. Or if you want it globally, it needs to be in the `'*'` key. See https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs for more info.

Comment: It seems to be in the `.dev` array block; see above.

Comment: Do you have a `'*'` block? Required for multi-environment configs.

Comment: Yes, there's a `'*'` block. `devMode` isn't in there because I don't want it globally.

Comment: Just ignore me... Patrick's answer is correct.